# i am making a wallpaper app in ionic but unable to lazy load my page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, loading, lazy-evaluation

i want to lazy load my page like i want to load image when the user scrolls down to that image area basically its a wallpaper app and the display is similar to tik-tok display

this is my upload-page.html

```
            <ion-header >
           <ion-toolbar >
           <ion-title style="text-align: center;color: blue;">Heading</ion-title>
          </ion-toolbar>
          </ion-header>





    <ion-content>
     <ion-card *ngFor="let image of allImages" (click)="setwall()">
      <img [src]="image"/>
   
      </ion-card>
  
 
</ion-content>
```

this is my uploadpage.ts

```
      import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
      import { AngularFireStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';

     @Component({
      selector: 'app-upload',
      templateUrl: './upload.page.html',
     styleUrls: ['./upload.page.scss'],
     })
     export class UploadPage implements OnInit {
 
     setwall(){
     (<any>window).plugins.wallpaper.setImage('Image/');
     }
      constructor(private storage: AngularFireStorage) { }

     allImages = [];
     ngOnInit() {
      this.getAllImages();
     }
      async getAllImages(){
      this.storage.ref("/Images/").listAll().subscribe((res)=>{
      console.log("images",res);
      res['items'].forEach(async (element) => {
        const img = await element.getDownloadURL();
        console.log("img",img)
        this.allImages.push(img);
      });
      });
      }
  
       }
```

Comment: use `<ion-img src="yourImgPath"></ion-img>` tag. it will make all image lazy load.

Answer (score 0):

You can use npm package for [ionic v2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-image-loader) [ionic v5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-image-loader-v5)

> Install the NPM Package

`npm install --save ionic-image-loader`

> Install Required Plugins

`npm i --save @ionic-native/file`

`ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-file --save`

`npm i --save @ionic-native/transfer`

`ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer --save`

> Import IonicImageLoader module and add IonicImageLoader.forRoot() in your app's root module

```
import { IonicImageLoader } from 'ionic-image-loader';

// import the module
@NgModule({
 ...
  imports: [
    IonicImageLoader.forRoot()
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

> Then add IonicImageLoader in your child/shared module(s)

```
import { IonicImageLoader } from 'ionic-image-loader';

@NgModule({
...
  imports: [
    IonicImageLoader
  ]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```